# jQuery UI Autocomplete Formatting for Multiple Elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have the jQuery UI Autocomplete setup to my liking and working perfectly, but there is one fatal flaw.  In my autocomplete I use a custom display [like this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data).  I have something very similar built but with on exception...

The only difference is that I have multiple autocomplete elements of the same class on that one page.  Only the first element shows the extra data line, the rest only show the basic autocomplete.

I can get the desired result by just iterating all of those class elements and calling the autocomplete on them, but I was hoping there was a better way of calling it once and having it "just work".

Here's how I'm adding the extra line:

```
.data( 'autocomplete' )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( '<li></li>' )
  .data( 'item.autocomplete', item )
  .append( '<a>' + item.label + '<br/><small>' + item.desc + '<small></a>' )
  .appendTo( ul );
};
```

I should note that I'm not getting any console exceptions at all.

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you ever get an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can make this work is by changing my code from:

```
addautocomplete($('.tagEntry'));
```

To:

```
$('.tagEntry').each(function() {
     addautocomplete(this);
});
```

Comment: This isn't what I would've expected, either. Hopefully `addautcomplete` adds the same function to each element, to save resources. I only use jQuery for prototyping these days, but I wonder if this is a bug, or if the authors decided to only have `autocomplete` work on the first selected element, and not all selected elements, and if so, why.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to override the function via the object **prototype**, instead of on a **single instance**.

```
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( '<li></li>' )
  .data( 'item.autocomplete', item )
  .append( '<a>' + item.label + '<br/><small>' + item.desc + '<small></a>' )
  .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Overwrite the function before activating any autocompletes, but after the script has loaded.

Comment: Thanks Josiah - One issue though.  I have multiple autocompletes on the same page that pull from different sources, only this one class requires a description.

Comment: @sshefer - Then you can do it the way you are. `$('#selector-for-particular-autocomplete').data( 'autocomplete' )._renderItem`. Remember that data is associated with an element. If you need to change some data associated with a particular element make sure your selector is unique.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem.  Only the first autocomplete with that class shows the extra data, not the rest of them.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @sshefer - Yes. Add a special class to the autocomplete that you want to behave differently, then use that class (or id) selector to overwrite the instance function `_renderItem`

Comment: I am currently doing that ($('input.myclass').data('autocomplete')._renderItem) but only the first input with that class gets the extra line rendered.  I have 3 more on that page that get the default autocomplete with just the item.label.  There are 3 identical inputs - only the first one loaded on the page gets the extra description line, the others do not.  The only way I have found to do this was to iterate over each one when the page loads.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
$(..).autocomplete(..).each(function () {
   $.data(this, "autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) { ... } })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as sshefer and I got the best solution for it:

Change the

```
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item )
```

by

```
$( ".input_class" ).each(function(){
    $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item )...
});
```