# jQuery UI - Autocomplete - Custom style?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the following code and it's working, getting values back etc, but the `<b> and <br>` tags show up as text rather than get rendered. I'd like the `item.id` and `item.label` to be on different lines, if possible the `item.id` bold:

```
 $( "#predictSearch" ).autocomplete({
 source: function( request, response ) {
  $.ajax({
   url: "index.pl",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {
    term: request.term
   },
   success: function( data ) {
    response( $.map( data.items, function( item ) {
     return {
      label: '<B>' + item.id + '</B><br>' + item.label,
      value: item.id
     }
    }));
   }
  });
 },
 minLength: 2
});
```

Comment: you mean to say HTML tags ? <b>--</b> etc ?

Comment: `<b>` tag is depricated use `<strong>` instead and `<br />` is better

Comment: instead of br use "\r\n" which is for new line but use double quotes not single quotes lol just incase ...

Comment: @Jatin yes if you look at the label: line I'm returning the id and label, I want one to be below the other on screen, so I try to add a <br> tag and it doesn't get rendered.

Comment: @Val I don't think \r\n is HTML for newline. Anything I put in single or double quotes is simply displayed as is, not rendered as HTML

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937033/jquery-ui-autocomplete-formatting-for-multiple-elements

Comment: @Val <b> tag is not deprecated - it's purpose is just redefined to "an element that represents a span of text to be stylistically offset from the normal prose without conveying any extra importance."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you have some extra code (ajax call) for the autocomplete that it may not need. But, you can just swap out the special characters that jquery puts in to escape the html in the 'open' event of the autocomplete.

```
$("#autocomplete_field").autocomplete({
source: "autocomplete.php",
minLength: 2,
open: function(event, ui){
       $("ul.ui-autocomplete li a").each(function(){
        var htmlString = $(this).html().replace(/&lt;/g, '<');
        htmlString = htmlString.replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
        $(this).html(htmlString);
        });
     }
});
```

Full example  http://www.jensbits.com/2011/03/03/jquery-autocomplete-with-html-in-dropdown-selection-menu/.

And, if you are using perl in the autcomplete, http://www.jensbits.com/2011/05/09/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-perl-and-mysql/ is an example for that.

Comment: Thank you Jen, this makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I am not sure, but i think this must be having performance issue. Open function shall be called each time user function inside the textbox and start search. Instead, _renderItem function could be used. Otherwise, its nice solution.

Comment: Regarding the perl example rather than print "Content-type: text/html \n\n"; I tend to print $query->header();, and use DBI place holders for SQL injection prevention. Thanks again

Comment: @Raoul Thanks for the tip on the DBI placeholders. I updated my code.

Comment: @iMatoria Doesn't renderItem fire every time the user starts a search as well. I am not sure myself and will look into it.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of Success event, use _renderItem event.

Live implementation at [Vroom](http://www.vroomvroomvroom.com/). Type airport, you shall notice an image at the left.

NOTE: `_renderItem` below has some complex calculation. Don't go by that, just utilize the idea.

```
$("#myInput")
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            delay: 10,
            source: function (req, responseFn) {
                //Your ajax call here returning only responseFn Array having item.id and item.id
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                //action upon selecting an item
                return false;
            }
        })
    .data("autocomplete")
        ._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a><span class='airoplane'>" + (item[0] + (item[2] == "" ? "" : ", " + item[2]) + (item[1] == "" ? "" : " (" + item[1] + ")")).replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(this.term).replace(/([\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\*\.\+\?\|\\])/gi, "\\$1") + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>") + "</span></a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

We solved this problem by adding the following code at the end of the function:

```
$("ul.ui-autocomplete li a").each(function(){
   var htmlString = $(this).html().replace(/&lt;/g, '<');
   htmlString = htmlString.replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
   $(this).html(htmlString);
});
```

Here the event open callback function is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Based on iMatoria's answer this is how I did it.

```
var jAuto = $('#purchaser-autocomplete input:text');

jAuto.autocomplete({
        source: URL
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            //Do Stuff
        }
    });

jAuto.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    var cssClass = "";
    if (item.id.substring(0,1) === 'S') { cssClass = " class='item-staff'"; }

    return $("<li" + cssClass + "></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
}

jAuto.focus();
```