# Add span tag in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I would like to style only specific elements/parts from this

**My code:-**

```
$('input[name=\'bar_home\']').autocomplete({
delay: 0,
minLength: 3,
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=common/home/autocomplete&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request.term),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {       
            response($.map(json, function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item.name + ' ' + '-' + ' ' + '%' + item.price,
                    value: item.product_id,
                }
            }));
        }
    });
}, 
select: function(event, ui) {
    url = 'index.php?route=product/product&product_id=' + ui.item.value;
    location = url;
    return false;
},
focus: function(event, ui) {
  return false;
 }
 }
 );
```

These are the two elements that I want to style

```
 '£', item.price
```

I want to style only the above 2 elements/parts. Like I want to change the color of only these two and not

```
   **item.name**
```

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: `label: item.name + ' ' + '-' + ' ' + '% <span class="class">' + item.price + '</span>',`

Comment: @Omar that doesn't seem to work as it adds '<span class="class">' as plain text which is visible alongside item.price. For e.g. %<span class="class">5</span>

Comment: True, then you may need to convert label and value into variables in order to add HTML tags.

Comment: @Omar Ok, can you also please tell me what I need to do after I convert them into variables? Do I just convert them as it is and then call that variable where I was calling label and value or do I need to do something else? Thanks.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992022/jquery-ui-autocomplete-custom-style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by following the instructions provided in the link that @Omar posted.

This is what I had to add right after the above code that I posted in my question:-

```
            $["ui"]["autocomplete"].prototype["_renderItem"] = function( ul, item) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( $( "<a></a>" ).html( item.label + '<span style="color:#CC3333">' + item.label2 + '</span>' ) )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

So this how my final code looked after adding it:-

```
    $('input[name=\'search_home\']').autocomplete({
delay: 0,
minLength: 3,
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=common/home/autocomplete&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request.term),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {       
            response($.map(json, function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item.name + ' ' + '-' + ' ',
                                            label2: '£' + item.price,
                    value: item.product_id,
                }
            }));

        }
    });
}, 
select: function(event, ui) {
    url = 'index.php?route=product/product&product_id=' + ui.item.value;
    location = url;
    return false;
},
focus: function(event, ui) {
  return false;
   }
   }

   );;
        $["ui"]["autocomplete"].prototype["_renderItem"] = function( ul, item) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( $( "<a></a>" ).html( item.label + '<span style="color:#CC3333">' + item.label2 + '</span>' ) )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

I hope anyone with the same problem will find this useful. Also, here is the link @Omar provided me with and using this, I found my solution:-

[jQuery UI - Autocomplete - Custom style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992022/jquery-ui-autocomplete-custom-style)